# Matlabpool does not open

Tags: parallel-processing, matlab

I have been using matlabpool before in this computer. The computer shutted down when was running a script using matlabpool. Now I cannot open matlabpool anymore. Running the validation give me the following error. Reinstalled the toolbox and still have the problem.

### --------------------------------------

Stage: Parallel Job

Status: Failed
Description:  The job creation or submission encountered a MATLAB exception.

Command Line Output: (none)

Error Report:
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in validateConfig>iGetLabInfoFromParallelJob (line 288)
    hostnames = outputArgs(:,1);

Error in validateConfig>iRunJobStage (line 379)
            [hostnames, labs] = getOutputFcn(job);

Error in validateConfig>doValidate (line 146)
completed = iRunJobStage(scheduler, config, timeout, validationClient, ...

Error in validateConfig (line 54)
    doValidate(validationClient, config, timeout);

Debug Log: (none)

Answer (score 0):

Close MATLAB and delete the following folders:

```
%APPDATA%\MathWorks\MATLAB\local_cluster_jobs
%APPDATA%\MathWorks\MATLAB\local_scheduler_data
```

Try again.  :)

Also, try going into Parallel -> Manage Cluster Profiles... -> click Validate on the "local" profile.

Comment: Did not work. Tried to validate it again returned same error shown.

Comment: Just checking.  My last suggestion would be to quit MATLAB and delete `parallel.settings` in the MATLAB version subfolder (e.g. R2013a) in `%APPDATA%\MathWorks\MATLAB`, as well as the folders above, again.

Comment: Correction for last comment -- BACKUP `parallel.settings`, then delete.  ;)